# Adding other certificates to existing jks or not using javax.net.ssl.trustStore for a request

Tags: java, spring, encryption, openssl, keytool

I'm running a spring application under Tomcat in linux. I'm using mongodb as my database service.

After searching a lot to find how to use SSL/TLS to connect to mongodb, I found that I have to add certificates to a java keystore and use them in my spring application like this.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/path/truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "apass");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "apass");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
```

and everything worked fine and I could connect to mongodb. But the problem is I send other HTTP requests from my application using Spring `RestTemplate`. After I configured my mongodb with SSL, I cant connect to any other external host.

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I generated my SSL certs using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790287/self-signed-ssl-connection-using-pymongo#35967188). And I used keytools as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736098/cant-connect-from-java-to-mongo-ssl-replica-set).

I am not expert in using keyTools or Key manager and I haven't had such experiences with ssl before.

**UPDATE**
Even after removing Clearing properties, or even shutting down the system, I still get the same exception. Its like the connection is still trying to use wrong ssl cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is create a custom truststore that replaces that provided by the JVM and yours does not contain all the well-known CA certificates used by public internet services. Hence you are getting trust-path errors when your end tries to validate a certificate off the internet.

The quickest workaround would be for you to *not* set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` properties. Instead, import your mongodb CA certificate into the JVM default truststore (usually the *cacerts* file). You will need to remember to repeat this if you replace/upgrade the JVM.

If you don't have the necessary permissions to modify *cacerts*, or you're on a shared server where it's forbidden then you could still use your custom truststore but augment it with all the well-known certificates in the *cacerts* file. You'll be responsible for maintaining it as and when new CA certs appear.

Comment: That sounds to be valid thing to do. I will test it. but what happened to my other certificates? Why cant my application connect to other servers through HTTPS any more? I mean the old certificates must be there.

Comment: Dont mind the question in my previous comment. I found out I have messed with the linux hostname.